# Find the biggest rectangle in a bar graph

Tags: c#, interview-questions

> Find the largest rectangle area on a bar graph. Example: if you had a graph of 1,4,5,3,3,5 the answer would be 15 (3x5) which is formed by the rectangle that is 3 high and spans from position 2 (1 based) to 6.

Please review my answer and comment about runtime complexity, memory usage, and basically anything else you think I need to improve if this was a job interview for your company.

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;

namespace Interviews
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            List<int> barGraph = new List<int>() { 1, 4, 5, 3, 3, 5 };
            int max = GetBiggestRectSize(barGraph);
            //should output 15
            barGraph = new List<int>() { 1, 4, 2, 3, 3, 5 };
            max = GetBiggestRectSize(barGraph);
            //should output 10
        }

        private static int GetBiggestRectSize(List<int> barGraph)
        {
            int maxRectSize = 0;
            int max = barGraph.Max();
            for (int i = 1; i <= max; i++)
            {
                int tempSize = 0;
                for (int j = 0; j < barGraph.Count; j++)
                {
                    if (barGraph[j] >= i)
                    {
                        tempSize += i;
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        if (tempSize > maxRectSize)
                        {
                            maxRectSize = tempSize;
                        }
                        tempSize = 0;
                    }
                    if (tempSize > maxRectSize)
                    {
                        maxRectSize = tempSize;
                    }
                }
            }
            return maxRectSize;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: The code seems correct but *very* inefficient. You need to come up with some smarter algorithm to solve it. This is a pretty well-known problem, I know of two approaches, one using a stack and the other using disjoint set union.

Comment: @RazimanT.V. thanks very much for the comment, http://www.geeksforgeeks.org/largest-rectangular-area-in-a-histogram-set-1/, I will not dig deeper into this.

Comment: will now dig deeper

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As others have pointed out, your algorithm is very inefficient. Especially if the size of the columns vary widely:

```
int[] columns = { 1, 5, 40000, 3 } // Just to make my point clear :-)
```

This will cause your algorithm to check 39996 numbers (= column heights) for no reason.

So a minor change in your code could make it a lot more efficient, although it isn't still a very efficient approach:

```
private int GetBiggestRectSize(List<int> barGraph)
{
  int maxRectSize = 0;
  //int max = barGraph.Max();

  // CHANGE: Instead of checking all values from max to 1 - only check values in the input graph.
  foreach (int i in barGraph)
  {
    int tempSize = 0;
    for (int j = 0; j < barGraph.Count; j++)
    {
      if (barGraph[j] >= i)
      {
        tempSize += i;
      }
      else
      {
        if (tempSize > maxRectSize)
        {
          maxRectSize = tempSize;
        }
        tempSize = 0;
      }
      if (tempSize > maxRectSize)
      {
        maxRectSize = tempSize;
      }
    }
  }

  return maxRectSize;
}
```